# How do I recover from Ultrahook Authentication Failed

Tags: rubygems

I'm using ultrahook ruby gem at the moment to hook into my testing machine.

[UltraHook](http://www.ultrahook.com/faq)
works great but periodically I get an error from ultrahook 'authentication failed'.

Is there any way to automatically restart the ultrahook service on my machine when this happens?

Comment: I've wrapped the command in a retry to restart it automatically. `for i in {1..10}; do ultrahook namespace http://localhost:3030 && break || sleep 5; done`. But it's far from ideal. I've sent a mail to the gem author, waiting on a reply.